# Radio Buttons in Shiny Modal Dialog

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am building a shiny app that, among other things, tries to identify a person's Census subdivision (in Canada) from an input postal code.  Occasionally, postal codes overlap multiple subdivisions, so when that happens, I want users to be able to choose which subdivision they want to see.  I was hoping to do it with a radio button input inside of a modal dialog. In the app below, the appropriate radio buttons appear, but I am unable to select a value. Each time I try to press one of the radio buttons, it appears to re-load the modal dialog without recording the choice.  I am wondering if there is a) a way to make this work that has escaped me or b) a better way to accomplish this same goal?  There are only two postal codes in the data frame that loads - `A0A1P0` which exhibits the problem and `N5X1G4`, which has only a single census subdivision and thus doesn't trigger the modal.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinycssloaders)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      splitLayout(
        textInput("pcode", NULL, value="", placeholder = "e.g., A1A1A1"), 
        actionButton("findpc", "Find Me!"))
    ), 
    mainPanel(
      withSpinner(verbatimTextOutput("mygeog"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  library(dplyr)
  load(file("https://quantoid.net/files/so/pccf_reprex.rda"))
  
  output$mygeog <- renderPrint({
    validate(need(input$findpc, ""))
    mypc <- gsub(" ", "", input$pcode)
    tmp_pc <- pccf_reprex
    tmp_pc <- as.data.frame(subset(tmp_pc, PC == mypc))
    if(nrow(tmp_pc) > 1){
      geog_chc <- c(tmp_pc$CSDuid)
      names(geog_chc) <- c(tmp_pc$CSDname)
      showModal(dedupModal(chc=geog_chc))
      tmp_pc <- tmp_pc[which(geog_chc == input$chooseGeog), ]
    }
    paste0("Geographic Indicator CSD: ", 
           tmp_pc$CSDname[1])
  })  
  
  dedupModal <- function(failed = FALSE, chc) {
    modalDialog(
      span('Your Post Code did not identify a unique CSD. Please pick the appropriate one from the list below.'),
      radioButtons("chooseGeog", "Choose Region", choices = chc, selected=character(0)),
      footer = tagList(
        actionButton("ok", "OK")
      )
    )
  }
  
  observeEvent(input$ok, {
    # Check that data object exists and is data frame.
    removeModal()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a suitable solution by putting an event observer around the "Find Me!" button and rendering the print output inside the event observer.  Here's the solution:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinycssloaders)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script("
    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('chooseGeog', function(value) {
      Shiny.setInputValue('chooseGeog', value);
      });
  "),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      splitLayout(
        textInput("pcode", NULL, value="", placeholder = "e.g., A1A1A1"), 
        actionButton("findpc", "Find Me!"))
    ), 
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("mygeog")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  library(dplyr)
  load(file("https://quantoid.net/files/so/pccf_reprex.rda"))
  
  output$trig <- renderUI({
    actionButton("trigger", "trigger")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$findpc, {
    mypc <- gsub(" ", "", input$pcode)
    tmp_pc <- pccf_reprex
    tmp_pc <- as.data.frame(subset(tmp_pc, PC == mypc))
    if(nrow(tmp_pc) > 1){
      geog_chc <- c(tmp_pc$CSDuid)
      names(geog_chc) <- c(tmp_pc$CSDname)
        showModal(dedupModal(chc=geog_chc))
    }else{
      session$sendCustomMessage("chooseGeog", tmp_pc$CSDuid[1])
    }
    output$mygeog <- renderPrint({
      req(input$chooseGeog)
      tmp_pc <- tmp_pc %>% filter(geog_chc == input$chooseGeog)
      paste0("Geographic Indicator CSD: ", 
           tmp_pc$CSDname[1])
  })
})
  

  dedupModal <- function(failed = FALSE, chc) {
    modalDialog(
      span('Your Post Code did not identify a unique CSD. Please pick the appropriate one from the list below.'),
      radioButtons("chooseGeog", "Choose Region", choices = chc, selected=character(0)),
      footer = tagList(
        actionButton("ok", "OK")
      )
    )
  }
  
  observeEvent(input$ok, {
    # Check that data object exists and is data frame.
    removeModal()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```